# Does this compound sentence act as the object of the preposition 'after'?

Tags: prepositions, object-complements

In the  construction

> The decision to block Mr. Sondland from being interviewed was delivered at the last minute, **after** the ambassador had already flown to Washington from Europe, and lawmakers had returned from a two-week recess to observe the questioning.

does the compound sentence

> the ambassador had already flown to Washington from Europe, and lawmakers had returned from a two-week recess to observe the questioning.

act as the object of the preposition *after*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the compound sentence . . . act as the object of the preposition *after*?

Essentially, yes; but *object* and *sentence* are not the terms preferred by most grammarians.

- Traditionalists call prepositions *subordinating conjunctions* when they introduce clauses, and they call the clauses *subordinate clauses*.
- Modernists call clauses introduced by prepositions *complements* rather than *objects*. (Some of them don't even call a noun clause introduced by a prepositions an *object*—they use *oblique* instead.) And they call finite clauses like those in your example *content clauses*.

This is not a comfortable time to be studying English syntax if you have to pass examinations.

Comment: This answer should serve as a model for all who are wise to follow: It perfectly separates substance from jargon. It points out that the substance of the OP's understanding was right even though it was expressed unconventionally _and_ it points out that there are different terminologies for expressing that idea, without declaring any one terminology the "true" one.